# Using javascript to fade out elements when one is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using java to make divs fade in and out when clicked on.

How would i make the three other functions fade out when one is clicked on while fading the clicked on fucntion in?

Heres the code so far;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#about').click(function(about){    
$('#outside, #outside2, #outside3, #outside4, #outside5, #outside6, #outside7, #outside8, #outside9, #outside10, #outside11').fadeToggle('slow');
});

$('#whyus').click(function(whyus){    
$('#outsidewhy, #outsidewhy2, #outsidewhy3, #outsidewhy4, #outsidewhy5, #outsidewhy6, #outsidewhy7, #outsidewhy8, #outsidewhy9, #outsidewhy10, #outsidewhy11').fadeToggle('slow');
});

$('#portfolio').click(function(port){    
$('#outsideport, #outsideport2, #outsideport3, #outsideport4, #outsideport5, #outsideport6, #outsideport7, #outsideport8, #outsideport9, #outsideport10, #outsideport11').fadeToggle('slow');
});

$('#contact').click(function(con){    
$('#outsidecon, #outsidecon2, #outsidecon3, #outsidecon4, #outsidecon5, #outsidecon6, #outsidecon7, #outsidecon8, #outsidecon9, #outsidecon10, #outsidecon11').fadeToggle('slow');
});


});
```

For example when function con is clicked on it should fade out function about, whyus and port while fading con in.

Another example, function about is clicked on it would fade out functions whyus, port and con while fading in about which is being clicked on.

Comment: create a fiddle first and show

Comment: how do you fade the functions?

Comment: you should use classes, not ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't be afraid of using classes.

For example, give every single sub-item a class of `class="outside"`

Then, also give a unique class to each of the 4 functions items. For example, give your `#outside, #outside2, #outside3....` all a class of `class="outside1"`

and your `#outsidewhy, #outsidewhy2 ...` all a class of `class="oustside2"`

Then give all your top level click links a class of `class="click-link"`

Then all you need to do is

```
$('.click-link').click(function() {

    var whichone = $(this).attr('id'); // gets the id of the click-link that was clicked

    $('.outside').fadeOut(800); // this fades out them all

    if (whichone === 'about') {

        $('.outside1').fadeIn(800); // but this will fadein the ones that you want, depending on which link was clicked

    }

    else if (whichone === 'whyus') {

        $('.outside2').fadeIn(800);

    }

    etc

    etc

});
```

Comment: Spent some time putting it all together but it leaves the clicked functions divs still in pilling them in top. I need them to fade out if another element is clicked.

Comment: Forgot to add thank you for your response! im messing around with some things to see if i can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yFLq/1/)***</kbd>

**Far from perfect answer, improvements will be strongly appreciated**

---

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#about').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.notme').not('#outside').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#outside').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#whyus').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.notme').not('#outsidewhy').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#outsidewhy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#portfolio').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.notme').not('#outsideport').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#outsideport').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#contact').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.notme').not('#outsidecon').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#outsidecon').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```